# My CAShapeLayer is not well centered in my View

Tags: swift, uiview, cashapelayer

I wan't to draw a circle in the grey View but it is not perfectly centered and I can't understand why.

I get the center of my view (circleView) and put it in the circle's center then i had CAShapeLayers to the superview

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()

let center = circleView.center
let height = circleView.frame.height

// First circle

let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: height/2-20 , startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: (2 * CGFloat.pi) - (CGFloat.pi / 2), clockwise: true)
shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 20
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(named: "color1")!.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1
        
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        

// Second circle

let circularPath2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: height/2-20, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: (2 * CGFloat.pi) - (CGFloat.pi / 2), clockwise: true)
shapeLayer2.path = circularPath2.cgPath
shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 20
shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor(named: "color")!.cgColor
shapeLayer2.strokeEnd = 0.5
        
view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
```

But here is what i get

[image]

I tried to get center of my view like this :

```
CGPoint(x: circleView.bounds.midX, y: circleView.bounds.midY)
```

and tried to add the shapeLayer to my circleView rather than the superview but it's not working neither.
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: The problem is that your shape layer has no size.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage layers is to subclass `UIView` and set the sizes, path points, etc in `layoutSubviews()`.

Here's a quick example based on your code (I don't know what your "color" or "color1" are, so I set them to green and systemGreen):

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        // set shape layer properties and add them as sublayers
        
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 20
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        //shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(named: "color1")!.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 20
        shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        //shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor(named: "color")!.cgColor
        shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        shapeLayer2.strokeEnd = 0.5
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)

    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let height = bounds.height
        
        // we can use the same path for both layers
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                        radius: height * 0.5 - 20.0,
                                        startAngle: -.pi * 0.5, // start at minus 90-degrees (12 o'clock)
                                        endAngle: .pi * 1.5,    // end at 270-degrees (also 12 o'clock)
                                        clockwise: true)

        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer2.path = circularPath.cgPath

    }
}
```

Now we add the view to a controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let circleView = CircleView()
        circleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(circleView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            circleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            circleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: circleView.widthAnchor),
            circleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            circleView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])

        circleView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

    }

}
```

and the result is:

[image]